# type matching error - why?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I get the following warning from gcc:

```
labs.c:760:2: error: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Werror=char-subscripts]
  wrbuf[cmdlen++]=(unsigned char)(basictoken[from]>>8);
  ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Debugging with gdb it reports both side of similar type:

```
760 wrbuf[cmdlen++]=(unsigned char)(token[from]>>8);
(gdb) whatis wrbuf[cmdlen]
type = unsigned char
(gdb) whatis (unsigned char)(token[from]>>8)
type = unsigned char
```

Why is this warning?
It disturbs me because if I want to make available format for ctypes the warning is turned to error.

Answer (score 3):

```
error: array subscript has type ‘char'
```

It's telling you about the **array subscript**, `cmdlen` or `from`.

How is `cmdlen` and `from` defined? Is one of them a char? I suspect so...

Comment: cmdle is char, from is int

Comment: well, changing cmdlen to int solves the question. However I'm a bit surprised why is mandatory to use an integer for a few bytes long array. :( Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Asking StackOverflow for the rational behind that would be a good question. Perhaps it's because in some instances the compiler doesn't know the size of the array and using a char as an index is questionable because of it's range. But, I don't know...

Comment: Let's see what they say... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897968/rationale-behind-warning-array-subscript-is-of-type-char