# Rationale behind 'warning: array subscript is of type 'char''?

Tags: c

I've often wondered about the rationale behind the `warning: array subscript is of type 'char'` warning. I know I can cast it to an int or turn the warning off with `-Wno-char-subscripts`, but why is this considered an issue worth warning about? Does it have to do with the small of range of char? Or something else I'm not thinking of?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
        char a[10], i = 0;
        a[i] = 0; // i is a char, hence the warning.
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: You are right, I didn't paste what I compiled! How many times have I ragged on people for doing that? Yikes. Let me edit...

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for the link. I looked but obviously not hard enough.

Comment: yeah. I know the feeling. Now it also warns-up on my clang as well.